# Deleting Array Element in Python, Issues with np.delete

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of coordinates among other things, I want to delete the number of objects I have in, say, quadrant I.  I tried using np.delete, but perhaps my loop is wrong since it only deletes one single object.  Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import scipy
def get_distance(x,y,x_center,y_center):
  d = (x - x_center)**2 + (y - y_center)**2
  d = sqrt(d)
return d

dataA=np.genfromtxt('match.txt')
c1=dataA[:,0]
c2=dataA[:,1]
d1=dataA[:,2]
d2=dataA[:,3]

for i in xrange(len(c1)):
   if c1[i] >= 0 and c1[i] <= 2288 and c2[i] >= 2288 and c2[i] <= 4576:
      new_a = np.delete(c1,i)
      new_b = np.delete(c2,i)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop build a list of i's that need to be deleted (e.g. del_list). Once you are done with the loop, you can delete the list of i's from c1 and c2

```
new_a = np.delete(c1, del_list)
new_b = np.delete(c2, del_list)
```